# Text based on hours and minutes

Tags: php, time

im trying to change text based on HOUR:MINUTES in php
I got it working for Hours but not minutes for example:

If time is 15:30 i want text to be "DUMMY"
if time is 15:33 i want text to be "NOT DUMMY"

Comment: Which logic is behind this? I mean what is your goal with this? Also where is your code?

Comment: Rizier123, are you sure you want to know the logic behind this? :D

Comment: please provide some code so we can see what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

From the amount of info you gave I can propose only this one:

```
$text = (date("H:i") === '15:30') ? "DUMMY" : "NOT DUMMY";
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's useful to build a function that turns the time into the time in minutes. Something as simple as:

```
function time2minutes($time)
{
  return 60*substr($time,0,2)+substr($time,3,2);
}
```

Then you can do any comparision in just minutes. The advantage of this is that you can add and substract this as well, or work with time ranges.

Comment: Your function will not work for his format. And still it does not resolve the problem of printing different texts at different points in time.

Comment: And you cannot figure out why? Ok, I corrected the function. Now it does work. Sorry, I should be more careful.

Comment: You see if I would tell you from the beginning you would not learn :) Still I gave you the clue about format issue :)